# Quadratic Functions Can $b = i$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

In a quadratic function $(f(x) = ax^2+bx+c)$, are $a$, $b$, and $c$ all limited to real numbers? If not, can $b = i$? ex: $(f(x) = ax^2 + ix + c)$? How would this affect the graph and quadratic formula to find its $x$-intercepts.

$x$ is still a real number.

Range of $x$: $(-∞,∞)$.

$a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants.

Also, I am sorry about the poor formatting earlier which had lead to misinterpretations.

Comment: It becomes a bit hard to graph in this situation, but the quadratic formula still works, and in the case of a purely imaginary $b$ you don't even have to deal with any square roots of complex numbers.

Comment: bear in mind that $b = i(ax^2 + ix +c)$ is *not* a constant.  So $f(x) = (a+i)x^2 + ix + (c+i)$ so you can use the quadratic equation on that ($x=\frac{-i\pm\sqrt{i^2 -4(a+i)(c+i)}}{2i}$) but you *CAN'T* use it on $$x =\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-(ax^2+ix+c^2)\pm\sqrt{(ax^2+ix+c^2)^2 -4ac}}{2a}$$.

Comment: @fleablood I think the slightly sloppy notation confused you, I think the question was just "can $b=i$, i.e. can I treat $ax^2+ix+c$?" The TeX source makes this a little bit more obvious because they are in different math environments just without any actual text between them except for a space.

Comment: Ah... well that makes more sense of the title and works. But the OP Ought to make it clear with text.  Perhaps like: "If $b=i$ and the function is $(ax^2 + ix + c)$".  If nothing else this is better *english*.  "Can $b = i$ $(ax^2+ix+c)$" is like saying "Can an animal be a penguin Zoo with penguin in it".... Anyway, yes, quadratic equation works just fine:  $x = \frac {-i\pm\sqrt{-1+4ac}}{2a}$.  But a minor issue is $x$ still supposed to be purely real, so $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ can $x$ be non-real and $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$. Either way you can use Quad. Form (provided the result is val)

Answer (score 1):

If $x,a,b,c$ are real numbers (purely real complex) then the $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ is a function from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.  The graph is one dimensional curve existing in two-dimensional space.

If $x$ is real and $a,b,c$ are (not all purely real) complex numbers then $f(x)$ is a function from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$. The graph is a one dimensional curve existing in three-dimensional space.

[Edit: *After considering Yves Daoust's answer and observation, I should point out that a function: $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ via $f(x) = (a_r + a_i i)x^2 + (b_r + b_ii)x + (c_r + c_i i) = (a_rx^2 + b_rx +c_r) + (a_ix^2 + b_ix + c_i)i$ the graph of which, does exist in 3-D space, it does so as a parabola contained in a plane; just not one of the planes defined by two of the dimensional axes.*]

If $x$ is complex (regardless of whether $a,b,c$ are all purely real complex or not) then $f(x)$ is a function from $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$.  The graph is a two-dimensional surface in a four-dimensional space.

The quadratic equation that $a^2z + bz + c = 0$ will have solutions $z = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt {b^2- 4ac}}{2a}$ will hold true whether $a,b,c$ or $z$ are are real or complex numbers.

So if $b = i$ and the function is $f(x) = ax^2 + ix + c$ then we can solve $f(x)=0$ via $x = \frac {-i\pm\sqrt {-1 - 4ac}}{2a}$.

(Note: if $x$ is restricted to be purely real, then this value, $\frac {-i\pm\sqrt {-1 - 4ac}}{2a}$ may not be purely real and not be a legitimate value for $x$.  In fact, if $a$ is real, then this can only be purely real if $-1 + 4ac = (k+i)^2$ for some real $k$ and then only $\frac {-i +(k+i)}{2a}=\frac k{2a}$ will be a solution; $\frac {-i-(k+i)}{2a} = \frac {-k-2i}{2a}$ will not be an acceptable real value for $x$.)

(Hmm, and if $c$ is real then $k = 0$ and $4ac=0$ and $c = 0$....  but if $a,$ can be non-real... well if $x$ must be real we still must have a purely real value for this to have a solution.)

.......

This assumes that  $a, b,$ and $c$ are constants.

You can not replace $b$ (or $a$ or $c$) with a value dependent upon $x$.

I first misread your question as replacing $b$ with  $i(ax^2+ix + c)$.  Although this seems not to have been your intent my initial explanation still is worth observing:

If we replace $b$ with  $i(ax^2+ix + c)$, we would have the function $f(x) = (a+i)x^2 + ix + (c+i)$.  This is a *different* quadratic.

And you can use the quadratic equation to solve it for $f(x) = 0$ then $x=\frac {-i^2 \pm \sqrt {i^2 + 4(a+i)(c+i)}}{2(a+i)}$.  If $x$ is restricted to real values  and the graph $(x,f(x))$ is a one dimensional curve in three dimensional space, these values may not be real, and there may be no real solution.

Comment: You misread the question. The OP meant "can $b=i$ ? (i.e. the trinomial be $ax^2+ix+c$)"

Comment: Yes, it seems I did misread the question.  But that doesn't change my answer and the observation that $b$ must be a constant.

Comment: As far as I know, $i$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

For real $x$,

$$ax^2+ix+c$$ represents a complex number with real part $ax^2+c$ and imaginary part $x$.

In the complex plane, you can see it as a parabola of parametric equation

$$\begin{cases}u=ax^2+c,\\v=x\end{cases}$$

or after elimination of $x$,

$$u=av^2+c.$$

---

You can picture this in 3D, using the coordinate system $(x,u,v)$. It still gives a parabola, inscribed in the plane $v=x$ (the first bissector plane of $xu$ and $uv$).

---

If you keep calling the $x$-intercepts the intersection points of the axis $x$ with the curve, there aren't any. Because $u=v=0$ is $ax^2+c=x=0$, which is impossible (unless $c=0$).

---

More generally, all coefficients can be complex, so that $ax^2+bx+c$ is

$$\begin{cases}u=a_rx^2+b_rx+c_r,\\v=a_ix^2+b_ix+c_i.\end{cases}$$

By combining these two equations you can obtain a relation of the form

$$x=pu+qv+r$$

so that

$$u=a_r(pu+qv+r)^2+b_r(pu+qv+r)+c_r,$$
still a parabola (in the complex plane).

Comment: Are you assuming that $x$ is purely real?  If $x$ is allowed to be non-real complex this is will not follow.  The OP was ambiguous about this.

Comment: @fleablood: yes, I am. The OP seems to only allow $a,b,c$ to be complex. We can plot the curve in 3D (otherwise we have a surface in 4D).

Comment: True.  But I'm mildly concerned that the OP may not have considered or recognizes the issue.